# Development server returned response error code: 503

Tags: react-native

I am trying the react-native [sample barcode app](https://github.com/ideacreation/react-native-barcodescanner). I am using the command `react-native run-android` to build and run the application.

The app gets installed on the device and I am getting this error:

> The development server returned response error code: 503

There are solutions for other error codes but not for 503. Can anyone help me?

Comment: just do `reload`. if  is npm not running, then do `npm start`

Comment: When i do reload too, it isn't working & showing the same screen with error message. What do you mean by npm start ?